# How to update Jenkins config.xml, with value that did not previously exist

Tags: jenkins, ant

We upgraded from Jenkins 1.609 to 2.106.  When we do a release we want to start a job build number with 1 (Number of builds since the start of the project).  We were doing this using a ant script to update the config.xml file, but it does not work in Jenkins 2.  The XML file layout has changed some since v 1.0.

While I am think that I no longer want to do a 'replace' (because there is nothing to replace, and I have tried multiple variations of this), I am not sure of the syntax and arguments that I want to use here, to place a value '1' here.  I think that I should be using Insert, but with what arguments.

This is the ant code...

```
<target name="replace.builds.all.time">
        <copy file="${BuildConfigPath}" tofile="${BuildConfigPath}.bak" overwrite="true" force="true" />
        <xmltask source="${BuildConfigPath}" dest="${BuildConfigPath}">
          <replace path="/project/buildWrappers/org.jvnet.hudson.tools.versionnumber.VersionNumberBuilder/versionNumberString/text()" withText="${VersionNumberString}"/>
          <replace path="/project/buildWrappers/org.jvnet.hudson.tools.versionnumber.VersionNumberBuilder/oBuildsAllTime/text()" withText="${BuildsAllTime}"/>
        </xmltask>
    </target>
```

The second 'replace' line, is where the problem is.

The 1.0 config.xml code looked like this.  You can see that oBuildsAllTime had an actual value...

```
  <buildWrappers>
    <org.jvnet.hudson.tools.versionnumber.VersionNumberBuilder plugin="versionnumber@1.4.1">
      <versionNumberString>${VERSION_NUMBER}</versionNumberString>
      <projectStartDate>1969-12-31 05:00:00.0 UTC</projectStartDate>
      <environmentVariableName>VERSION_NUMBER</environmentVariableName>
      <oBuildsToday>-1</oBuildsToday>
      <oBuildsThisMonth>-1</oBuildsThisMonth>
      <oBuildsThisYear>-1</oBuildsThisYear>
      <oBuildsAllTime>-1</oBuildsAllTime>
      <skipFailedBuilds>false</skipFailedBuilds>
      <useAsBuildDisplayName>true</useAsBuildDisplayName>
    </org.jvnet.hudson.tools.versionnumber.VersionNumberBuilder>
    <EnvInjectPasswordWrapper plugin="envinject@1.92.1">
      <injectGlobalPasswords>true</injectGlobalPasswords>
      <maskPasswordParameters>false</maskPasswordParameters>
      <passwordEntries/>
    </EnvInjectPasswordWrapper>
  </buildWrappers>
```

The 2.0 config.xml is different in that there is no value for 0BuildsAllTime...

```
 <buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.timestamper.TimestamperBuildWrapper plugin="timestamper@1.8.9"/>
    <org.jvnet.hudson.tools.versionnumber.VersionNumberBuilder plugin="versionnumber@1.9">
      <versionNumberString>10.1.09.${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}</versionNumberString>
      <projectStartDate>1969-12-31 05:00:00.0 UTC</projectStartDate>
      <environmentVariableName>VERSION_NUMBER</environmentVariableName>
      <environmentPrefixVariable/>
      <oBuildsToday/>
      <oBuildsThisWeek/>
      <oBuildsThisMonth/>
      <oBuildsThisYear/>
      <oBuildsAllTime/>
      <worstResultForIncrement>SUCCESS</worstResultForIncrement>
      <skipFailedBuilds>false</skipFailedBuilds>
      <useAsBuildDisplayName>true</useAsBuildDisplayName>
    </org.jvnet.hudson.tools.versionnumber.VersionNumberBuilder>
  </buildWrappers>
```

I want to be able to insert the new  build number into the config.xml file, using ant code.

Comment: I need a little help here.  When I look at my posting, I do not see the code that I entered.  If I go into edit, I can see it.  How to correct?

Comment: click on the {} and then paste your code there , it should show.